# mysql has stopped on my centos 6.5 server and failed to restart

Tags: mysql

I have tried to restart my mysqld on Centos server but gives me the below error :

170731 05:53:58 mysqld_safe Directory '/data/mysql' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
MySQL Daemon failed to start.

I have checked my mysql.sock file and is present where it should be and as defined in my.cnf
I have checked the permissions also and they are also perfect.
Any other reason its failing to restart ?

Comment: Well can you provide some more logs?

Comment: There is nothing recorded in the error logs

Comment: You sure you run as the correct user then? Maybe try magic sudo [command]?

Comment: Logged in as a root user in putty to restart. But didnt work. Should I still go forward with sudo service mysqld restart ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant settings in your my.cnf and check if your folder: "/data/mysql/ exists? (by run: "df /data/mysql")

Comment: /data/mysql exists. I tried connecting other database server with php scripts. Still it gives permission denied error. I suppose there is an issue with some permissions somewhere

Comment: Well there is no connection with your problem and "connecting to another database server with PHP scripts"?

Can you run "ls -lhs /data/" then and add it to your question. Looks like a permission error  to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission error to me, try the following command.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /data/mysql
```

This command makes the owner(group) of the folder `/data/mysql` to the user and group '`mysql`'

After that the mysql-server should start again when running `sudo service mysqld restart`

Comment: Checked that. This wasnt the issue

Comment: Well, in that case the /data/mysql folder doesn't exists. You should really give us more information in order to help you. For example: 1. my.cnf-content. 2. Printscreen op de "ls -lhs /data" command.